# i am trying to create a programme which calculates the tax for a gym membership and there is an error which i can not fix

Tags: python-3.x

```
def tax():
    tax == 10
    membership = {'social' , 'sport'}

    membership = input("please enter the type of membership")
    months = input("please enter number of months overdue")
    if membership == 'sport':
        cost = months * 100 * 100/tax
        print ("the penalty is £",cost)
    elif membership == 'social':
        cost = months * 25 * 100/tax
        print ("the penalty is £",cost)
    else:
        print ("there is not penalty")

tax()
```

#### this is the code which I have created and the error below is what was thrown by python 3 the dash/ is supposed to divide the number

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/D/python/tax.py", line 16, in <module>
    tax()
  File "D:/D/python/tax.py", line 8, in tax
    cost = months * 100 * 100/tax
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'function'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using tax for both the method name and the tax rate. Python cannot figure out which one you want when you call `cost = months * 100 * 100/tax`.

```
def calculate_tax():
    tax = 10
    membership = {'social' , 'sport'}

    membership = input("please enter the type of membership")
    months = input("please enter number of months overdue")
    if membership == 'sport':
        cost = int(months) * 100 * 100/tax
        print ("the penalty is £",cost)
    elif membership == 'social':
        cost = int(months) * 25 * 100/tax
        print ("the penalty is £",cost)
    else:
        print ("there is not penalty")
```

Comment: that you for this it has helped with my understanding please forgive my amateur thinking as I am studying python for GCSE and haven't really grasped python yet

Comment: Happy to help, @ThePythonAmateur.

Comment: I have met a problem as it is price I would like it to print two decimal places to show price but it currently only shows one decimal place

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems that can be summerized by looking at :

```
def tax():
    tax == 10
    ...
```

You created a function called `tax`, then attempted to create a variable with the same name. `==` is used to check equality though, not assign, so you never actually created the variable in the second line.

- Don't create variables that have the same name as existing functions. Change your function or variable name to something else for neatness sake. The fact that you used the same name for each made this error more convoluted than it needed to be.
- Use `=` to assign variables, not `==`.
- As someone else mentioned, you're also not parsing the input before trying to use it. You need to call `int` on `months` before trying to do math on it.

Comment: thank you for this it was quite helpful I was unaware that this error would occur

Answer (score 0):

Line 8 should be:

```
cost = int(months) * 100 * 100/tax
```

Right now you're truing to multiply a string. You'll need to change the formula in both places.

Edit: Also, I'm not sure what you're intent is for the formula, but right now it is going to mmultiply `months` by 100 twice, then divide by `tax`.

Comment: thank you for this and I didn't realise this would happen as I thought that python reads from right to left when calculating thank you

Comment: No problem. I just want to mention, the above answers are wrong about naming a variable in a function the same as the function. For example: `def sum(x):
    sum = x+2
    print(sum)`
    
`sum(8)` prints `10` with no errors. The only problem with the `tax` variable is that it needs to be assigned `tax = 10`.